# IB and Named jpeg images not recognized in Xcode 10 beta

Tags: ios11, xcode10

UIImage(named: imageFileName) returns nil and IB images are not recognized in Xcode-10-beta builds on iOS11 iPhone & iPad devices; but no problem on iOS12 devices. Is there a work around?

Answer (score 0):

A work around for Xcode 10 beta builds on iOS11 devices is to replace the JPEG images with PNG versions. The problem doesn't appear to exist for for Xcode 10 beta builds on iOS12 devices. Bug report filed on 6/5/18.